# JAX-RS @PathParam to inject in class member variable?

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

I want to do something like this:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/sensors/{sensorid}/version")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML})
public class SensorVersionRestView extends VersionRestView{

    @PathParam("sensorid")
    private String sensorid;

    @GET
    @Path("count")
     // so the complete path is i.e. 
     // domain.com/rs/sensors/111211/version/count
    public void getCount() {

        // do something with the sensorId....

    }
}
```

But the only thing I get is `null` on runtime (I use Glassfish v3 with Jersey). The compiler and eclipse never mentions a problem with the `@PathParam` at the member class variable.

What's wrong with my construct?

The main problem is, why I doesn't want to use the whole path on each method in this class, that there exists another class which handles some rest operations on the sensor layer (deomain.com/rs/sensors/count i.e.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you need to change it to this:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/sensors/{sensorid}/version")
public class SensorVersionRestView extends VersionRestView {

@GET
@Path("count")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML})
 // domain.com/rs/sensors/111211/version/count
public void getCount(@PathParam("sensorid") String sensorid) {
    // do something with the sensorId....
}
}
```

Comment: Also I think @Stateless is unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

> Because injection occurs at object
>   creation time, use of this annotation
>   on resource class fields and bean
>   properties is only supported for the
>   default per-request resource class
>   lifecycle. Resource classes using
>   other lifecycles should only use this
>   annotation on resource method
>   parameters. - [JSR-311 Javadocs](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html)

You should be able to annotate fields with `@PathParam` as long as the resource class lifecyle is per-request.  By default the life-cycle of root resource classes is per-request.

EDIT: I don't think you can achieve this using EJBs.  If you remove the `@Stateless` annotation, it should work.

Comment: Why do I want this functionality without EJB in a server environment? This is another strange thing in the specification!